# transforming hierarchy table into bridge

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this original table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Hierarchies') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Hierarchies

CREATE TABLE #Hierarchies
    (
      [HierarchyId] [INT] NOT NULL ,
      [HierarchyName] NVARCHAR(MAX),
      [ParentHierarchyId] [INT]
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Hierarchies]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [HierarchyId] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON )
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO #Hierarchies ([HierarchyId], [HierarchyName], [ParentHierarchyId])
SELECT 1 , 'A', NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 'B', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 'C', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 , 'D', 2

SELECT * FROM #Hierarchies

SELECT 
    b.HierarchyId,
    a.HierarchyId
FROM #Hierarchies a
CROSS JOIN
 #Hierarchies b
 ORDER BY b.HierarchyId
```

and would like to transform it into this format:

```
ParentId    ChildId LevelsRemoved
1   1   0
1   2   1
1   3   1
1   4   2
2   2   0
2   4   1
3   3   0
```

Before I try to implement the wheel, I was wondering if someone could be so kind and point me to an existing sql script for this? Thanks.

Comment: What does LevelsRemoved Column mean?

Comment: Your desired output is not at all clear to me. What are you trying to do? Have you ever considered using nested sets instead of this type of adjacency list? They are much easier to work with.

Comment: Yeah I have used this and recursive CTEs but I need it in this format (called bridge pattern in the dimensional world).

Comment: @BI Dude LevelsRemoved is the number of steps between parent and child (or grant child etc.)

Comment: Why do you need Levels Removed if it is bridge table? I believe you should be fine with just distinct ParentID & ChildID

Comment: It makes reporting easier ... pls have a look here: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Schema-Complete-Reference-Christopher-Adamson/dp/0071744320 avoiding recursive CTEs etc.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get why you want to avoid CTE. Here is a solution with CTE.

```
WITH Descendant AS(
   SELECT HierarchyId AS ParentId, HierarchyId As ChildId, 0 AS LevelsRemoved
   FROM #Hierarchies

   UNION ALL

   SELECT D.ParentId, H.HierarchyId AS ChildId, D.LevelsRemoved + 1 AS LevelsRemoved
   FROM Descendant D
   JOIN Hierarchies H ON D.ChildId = H.ParentHierarchyId
)
SELECT * FROM　Descendant
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah this would be part of the transformation. Btw, the formatting is a bit wonky (-: